# Styling drag and drop uploading only html/css

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a drag and drop field for files and so far I have been able to style it however I wish. Except I need to somehow add text that says 'drag and drop' inside the area. I'm not really sure how to accomplish this.

I have tried adding `content:'drag and drop';`

And I have tried a background image, but it was not scalable and not something that I believe is the right solution.

my html looks like this

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="uploadCover" value="" />
```

and my css looks like this

```
input[type="file"]{
  padding-bottom: 4em;
  padding-top: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed #000;
}

input[type="file"]:hover{
  border: 1px dashed #67a5c5;
}
```

and the field looks like this...ignore the ugly yellow!

[image]

Any help or ideas would be wonderful! I'm really trying to avoid javascript.

Answer (score 0):

How about this for a starting point? It uses a `:after` pseudo element, so that the content you're adding follows the control itself.

It is "centre aligned" (using `margin auto 50%`) to avoid overlapping the filename text, but you'll probably need add some more CSS to make sure this doesn't happen on your web page.

```
input[type="file"]:after {
    content: "Drag and drop";
    display: block;
    min-width: 20em;
    margin: auto 50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jrG7v/

Edit: as pointed out this only works in Chrome. No text is displayed in Firefox, and IE11 (seems I've been upgraded since I last used IE10) still displays the text-style input box. Hopefully somebody else has a better answer.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much. :after never comes to my mind for some weird reason! :)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't even think to check ff.

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility with browsers, I'd go with:

```
<div>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="uploadCover" value="" />
    <div class="drag">Drag and Drop</div>
</div>

div.drag { min-width: 100px; margin-top: -25px; padding-left: 10px; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px;}
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/jrG7v/3/

Comment: This moves any content I have after it though because of the negative margins

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jrG7v/5/ If u put inside a div probably not, take a look. U could also use clear:both in the next element if necessary

Comment: Yes it does. Try changing that margin to margin-top: -50px; and clearing is for when you use floats..not margins.